# ssh key works on shell login, refuses to run screen

Tags: ssh

I am logging into a centos7 system from windows using ssh with a rsa public key.

This works fine if I want a shell and run

```
ssh <user>@<host>
```

Now I want to use screen on the host, so I try to login using

```
ssh <user>@<host> "screen -r 6204"
```

where 6204 is an existing screen session. But If I do this, I get

> warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
>
> Must be connected to a terminal.

What is going on here? I can fix the setup on both sides.

Comment: Two separate issues: (1) The warning is probably printed after `ssh <user>@<host>`  as well, but you don't notice because the remote shell clears the screen. (2) Allocate tty: `ssh -t ...` (see `man 1 ssh`). // The issues are independent, your question should address exactly one of them. Which one should it be? If the latter, then you can write an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)

You're probably using an older version of PuTTY's "Pageant" which doesn't carefully look at the signing requests it receives – it's asked to sign using one algorithm, but instead uses another.

When making digital signatures (like during SSH authentication), the data to-be-signed is first hashed using some hash functions. When SSHv2 was first defined, it specified that SHA-1 is to be used for `ssh-rsa` keys – which made sense when 1024-bit RSA keys were the norm, but has since become a weak part in the system.

Instead of defining a second incompatible RSA key type, the SSH Agent protocol was adjusted so that the client could ask the agent for different signature types using the same RSA key. Old agents were expected to respond with "invalid request" and the client would try again, but Pageant doesn't check carefully enough and just makes a signature with the wrong type.

This was fixed in PuTTY version 0.71. If you want to get rid of the warning, **upgrade PuTTY** and restart Pageant.

(Of course, this can also apply to other SSH clients, although I don't remember OpenSSH itself being affected. But in any case, the issue is with whatever SSH agent you're using.)

> Must be connected to a terminal.

When you run `ssh <host>`, the client requests that the server create a "pseudo-terminal device" (/dev/pts/# or /dev/ttyp# depending on OS) – the remote program then thinks it is talking to a terminal emulator. The pty device allows reporting the window size (lines×columns), translates LF newlines to CRLF and back, and so on.

When you run `ssh <host> <command>`, the client *doesn't* request a pty device by default, because in many cases its functionality is not wanted – the translation layer could easily corrupt the data being transferred.

But if you *are* trying to run an interactive command this way, **use the `-t` option** to re-enable pseudo-terminal mode:

```
ssh -t <host> "screen -r 6204"
```